# Django How to Look up querydict in template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

when i look inside querydict it with `{{get_copy}}` it shows

```
<QueryDict: {'grub_id__in': ['Yelek', 'Tunik', 'Tulum', 'Tshirt']}>
```

as i know that how to look up querydict

```
{%for key,val in get_copy.items%}
{{key}}{{val}}
{%endfor%}
```

but it shows only one of val value

***output:***

```
grub_id__in Tshirt
```

Answer (score 1):

From the **`QueryDict.items()`** of [**QueryDict objects[Django-doc]**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/#id1)

> Like dict.items(), except this uses the same **last-value** logic as **getitem**() and returns an iterator object instead of a view object.

And the **`QueryDict.__getitem__(key)`** as stated

> Returns the value for the given key. If the key has more than one value, it returns the **last value**. Raises django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError if the key does not exist.

So you can use **`QueryDict.getlist(key, default=None)`** as stated

> Returns a list of the data with the requested key. Returns an empty list if the key doesn’t exist and default is None. It’s guaranteed to return a list unless the default value provided isn’t a list.

In your `views.py`

```
from django.http import QueryDict
from django.shortcuts import render

def get_copy(request):
    data = QueryDict('grub_id__in=Yelek&grub_id__in=Tunik&grub_id__in=Tulum&grub_id__in=Tshirt')
    return render(request, 'test.html', {'get_copy':data.getlist('grub_id__in')})
```

And in your `templates`

```
{{get_copy}}
```

Output

```
['Yelek', 'Tunik', 'Tulum', 'Tshirt']
```

Comment: Thanks, get_copy is a copy of the url attributes so i need the content of the key and the key is not always grub_id__in it could change. So can you help me?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add `urls` and also `views`  for corresponding code ?

Comment: I've solved it by converting get_copy to string and now I'm getting the data as I want.

Answer (score 0):

Add space befor/after "%":  {%_ .... _%}